# which version of pydev should I install with python 2.6.6

Tags: python, eclipse-plugin, pydev, python-2.6

New to python, hence the question...

I am going to be working with python 2.6.6 and I am trying to set up my eclipse on CentOS for the same. While trying to get the pydev version I don't know which version I should get? I see a bunch of them listed for 2.6.x.x and 2.7.x.x. Can I select the latest one in the version series 2.7?

How does this matter with me working with a specific older version of python.

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to http://pydev.org/download.html, the latest version of PyDev supports Python 2.1 or later, no qualifications.  So you should be OK with Python 2.6.6 and at least could ask for support if you run into a problem with it.

Sorry to hear your initial experiences with Python have to be with an older version of the interpreter!

Comment: thanks! I installed the latest one-- so far no problems.